# SQL command is not giving expected result in Laravel 5.7. Do I need to modify my table or my query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have my table data like below photo.

[image]

My expected data should be like this below photo.

[image]

My implemented laravel SQL code is like below.

```
$img = DB::table('table_name')
->select('table_name.user_id','table_name.post_id','table_name.name')
->groupBy('table_name.user_id')
->get();
```

Comment: Your expected result suggests that you should be grouping on `post_id`, and not `user_id`.

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: I am getting error. Error code is "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 "

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it. This way it's cleaner and working for me.

```
$img = DB::table('table_name')->select('user_id','post_id','name')
                              ->groupBy('post_id')
                              ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$img = DB::table('table_name')
 ->select('user_id','post_id','name')
 ->groupBy('post_id')
 ->get();
```

If you're running into this `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055` error be sure to check that the groupBy parameter is a valid column on the table